How do I enumerate the Faces of a Polyhedral Graph?
I am working on software for rendering polyhedral graphs. this category of graphs happens to be undirected and unweighted.
i am trying to efficiently enumerate the faces / peripheral cycles of these graphs.
I've found and implemented a satisfying solution for enumerating chordless simple cycles, but notably, this solution includes cycles which are not faces, such as the three cycles of length 4 which hug the meridians of an octahedron.
previously, i had been using eulers polyhedron formula to stop solving once 2 + E - V cycles had been found, but this is insufficient for edge cases in which these non-face cycles might be found before face cycles.
am i missing something obvious? trying to research planar embedding makes my head spin,,,, id deeply appreciate any help.
Example using octahedral graph

If you’re dealing with graphs embedded in ${\textbf R}^3$, then which cycles constitute faces depends on what embedding you have chosen. Am I missing something?

If you accept the subclass of Wythoffian polytopes (kaleidoscopical constructed uniforms), then you might derive some benefit out of the according Coxeter-Dynkin diagram.

@PaulTanenbaum yes; the graphs are planar but different embeddings can produce different cycles. i suppose i'm asking how that embedding step actually works and how the cycles are then derived from it.
currently, im just working with a distance matrix, i dont know what the right way to represent this data actually looks like and i'm not mathematically literate enough to consume research in the area. all the research i do kind of waves off the details as "do the embedding" or "enumerate the faces" without explicating how

Terminology: a graph’s cycles are properties of the graph itself, and thus are independent of any way one might embed it.

@PaulTanenbaum thank you for the correction; I'm still new to a lot of the terminology here and I'm struggling to articulate my question in a way that is comprehensible to google and maybe even to other humans haha.

It is really unclear to me what you are actually trying to enumerate.  Faces?  Cycles?  Chordless cycles?

@PaulTanenbaum is there a simple way to test if a cycle partitions a graph into disconnected subgraphs? i believe that would very quickly solve my issue. otherwise, i feel like i need a completely different approach than enumerating simple cycles after computing the distance matrix

@DanielV if you look at the attached example picture- you'll see that I'm successfully enumerating simple chordless cycles. this was my intuition for how to enumerate faces. there are many chordless cycles, however, that are not faces. i either need a completely different approach to solve for faces directly, or a way to determine if a given simple chordless cycle partitions a graph into disconnected subgraphs, which would characterize it as not being a face and allow me to discard the cycle as i search for true faces.

What is your conception of partition? Are you picturing deleting the cycle (its vertices and its edges) and considering the remainder? Deleting only the cycle’s edges? Some third thing?

I am curious about how the graphs in this problem can be "dense". Planar graphs are quite sparse: for $n$ vertices, they have at most $3n-6$ edges out of a possible $\binom n2$. If the graph is dense, it does not have a plane embedding, and we do not faces to find.

@MishaLavrov I believe I have again misused some terminology, then. Apologies. These are planar graphs, but apparently I misunderstand the concept of density here.

So what is wrong with saying "I want to enumerate the faces of a polytope represented by a planar graph" ?

For any cycle in a planar graph, including your example graph, there exists an embedding in ${\textbf R}^3$ such that cycle is a face of the convex hull.

@DanielV I don't understand, that's the title of my post; I am trying my best to communicate that that is the solution I am seeking.

And there’s a difference between a planar graph and a plane graph.  The former means a graph that can be embedded in the plane with no edge crossings. The latter means a plane embedding of a planar graph.

So is what you’re interested in the cycles $C’$ in a given straight-line plane embedding of a graph such that no vertex is contained in the interior of the polygon corresponding to $C’$?

What, exactly, does your input look like? I mean what form does it take?

@PaulTanenbaum i believe you've nailed it, yes. apologies for my shortcomings in communication

@PaulTanenbaum currently, in my software, i'm just using a distance matrix, D, where $D_{ij} = 1$ iff $i, j$ is an edge. when $i = j$, $D_{ij} = 0$, and when $i, j$ is disconnected, $D_{ij} = -1$.
This representation has been sufficient for enumerating simple chordless cycles, for finding shortest paths, etc, but I don't know if it's sufficient for the task at hand.

Then you don’t have an embedding. To see why that’s a problem, imagine the graph with 8 vertices and 12 edges that permits an embedding in 3-space as a cube. Consider the shadow that the wire-frame cube casts on the wall. As you twist and rotate the cube around, (the shadow of) any of its vertices can seem to pass in and out of (the shadow of) any of the three faces of the cube on which that vertex is not incident. That’s an illustration of what l meant by saying that so much depends on one’s choice of plane embedding.

I will assume that the graph really is polyhedral (in the sense that it is the skeleton graph of a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb R^3$; the graph-theoretic consequence is that the graph is $3$-connected, and that the embedding is combinatorially unique). Without this assumption, it is not necessarily true that every face really is a chordless cycle.
Moreover, in a polyhedral graph, chordless cycles that are not faces will divide the graph into multiple fragments. That is, if $C$ is a chordless cycle in $G$, the graph $G-V(C)$ obtained from $G$ by deleting every vertex of $C$ will not be connected. (In the matrix representation, this corresponds to deleting the rows and columns corresponding to vertices of $C$.)
Testing $G-V(C)$ for connectivity can be done efficiently. Choose a vertex, for example, and do a breadth-first search from that vertex. $G-V(C)$ is connected if and only if you will see every other vertex. (There is also an algebraic characterization from a slightly different matrix representation: the Laplacian matrix. This is usually not the most efficient approach, but it can sometimes be easier to implement.)
So if we enumerate all the chordless cycles, then we will eventually determine which are the faces with this method.
In larger graphs, this may be less efficient, because there are too many chordless cycles. In principle, it is possible to take a divide-and-conquer approach with these: when a chordless cycle is encountered, there should be a (unique, in polyhedral graphs) division of the components of $G-V(C)$ into components on one side of the cycle, and components on the other side. Then, we can split $G$ into two graphs $G_1, G_2$ that only have the vertices of $C$ in common, and repeat the search for faces on $G_1$ and $G_2$ separately. This is more complicated, though, and depending on how big the polyhedral graphs in question get, this may not be necessary.
